# HighCharts StockChart (Candlestick + Columnrange) overlay not showing correctly on different zoom levels

Tags: highcharts, stock

I have specific problem with overlaying columnrange over stockchart in HighCharts. I am trying to create a heatmap overlay with levels where limit order amounts are mostly aggregated. An example of something that I would like to achieve is:

[Example of heatmap chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBdsM.png)

So far I figured out I can overlay columnrange over stock chart, to map those areas. Unfortunately there is a bug or I am doing something wrong here... This is what I came up with:

https://jsfiddle.net/xnappp/1m30xb2v/

```
var candle_series = []
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', "https://localhost/api/ohlc", false);
try {
  xhr.send();
  if (xhr.status === 200) {
    candle_series = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
  } else {
    console.error(`HTTP error! Status: ${xhr.status}`);
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Request error:', error);
}

var color_series = []
const xhr_color = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr_color.open('GET', "https://localhost/api/walls", false);
try {
  xhr_color.send();
  if (xhr_color.status === 200) {
    color_series = JSON.parse(xhr_color.responseText);
  } else {
    console.error(`HTTP error! Status: ${xhr_color.status}`);
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Request error:', error);
}
console.log(color_series)

Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
  chart: {
    height: '650px'
  },
  series: [{
    id: 'btc',
    name: 'BTC Price',
    type: 'candlestick',
    data: candle_series,
    zIndex: 1
  }, {
    type: 'columnrange',
    name: 'Amount',
    linkedTo: 'btc',
    animation: false,
    findNearestPointBy: 'y',
    cropThreshold: 0,
    pointInterval: 0,
    grouping: false,
    groupPadding: 0,
    data: color_series,
    zIndex: 0
  }],
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
        "turboThreshold": 0
    }
  },
  rangeSelector : {
    enabled: false
  },
  navigator: {
    enabled: false
  }
});
```

For now chart looks like this:
[Default chart is broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlVUt.png)

But when you zoom in, the levels start showing up as they should. See example of this same graph, but zoomed in:
[Example of zoomed in graph working correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBT8O.png)

Basically the whole thing kinda works, but breaks when stock chart starts "aggregating" data and just breaks the whole thing.

Any hint on what I'm missing here would be awesome. Thanks to everyone in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It seems range series is not correct series to use. Correct one would be scatter! I managed to solve it after hours of debugging and testing, here is the result of final solution:

[Working example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JORm2.png)

Here is the stock chart code that I used, for everyone needing such solution:

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
  chart: {
    height: '650px'
  },
  series: [{
    id: 'btc',
    name: 'BTC Price',
    type: 'candlestick',
    data: candle_series,
    enableMouseTracking: false, // Disable mouseover hover effect
    events: {
      click: function () {
        return false; // Disable click event
      }
    },
    states: {
      hover: {
        brightness: 1 // Disable dimming effect
      }
    },
    zIndex: 1
  }, {
    type: 'scatter',
    name: 'Amount',
    data: transformedCandleSeries,
    color: 'red',
    marker: {
      symbol: 'square',
      radius: 1
    },
    states: {
      hover: {
        brightness: 1 // Disable dimming effect
      }
    },
    zIndex: 0
  }],
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
        "turboThreshold": 0
    }
  },
  rangeSelector : {
    enabled: false
  },
  navigator: {
    enabled: false
  }
});
```